# Managing GoogleDrive to use fileprovider or not

Tags: google-apps

Google is rolling out FileProvider usage per Google account for a year now. This results that there are different user experiences (even within 1 Google Workspace domain). Some users are activated with FileProvider, and some are not (Mac hardware / software is exactly the same).
Google have not documented anything how to force or stop fileprovider for an account. Google support is only talking about the rollout is in progress and we need more patience.

However we want to equalize the user experience for all our users, and since it looks like Apple is pushing all Cloud Providers to use FileProvider, we want to be able to force all users to use this.

What I found out so far is that if you have an account where fileprovider is activated, your second added account (in Google drive App) will also use fileprovider as long as the first account is active on that Mac. As soon as you de-activate your first account, the secondary is migrated back to /volumes (so FileProvider is de-activated)

I’ve found a way to prevent fileprovider to be activated (for an account where FileProvider is rolled-out to). This is done by logging out the account in GoogleDrive, and add an empty file called “fp_exit_beta” to the “~/Library/Application Support/Google/DriveFS” folder. After logging in again it will use the Volumes location instead of fileproviders CloudStorage.

However, I’m now looking for a method to force the fileprovider activation on a mac for an Google account where FileProvider is not yet rolled-out to. I’ve found [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420959/spotlight-indexing-of-google-drive-file-stream-disabled-on-restart) where they modify an account specific config file, and in this file we should also be able to activate FileProvider.

Q1 Does anyone have succes forcing FileProvider in any way?

Q2 While trying to find a way by using the python script in the link above, is there someone that have a better understanding of reading and writing to protobuf binary files? it might help if we can replace the python script with bash or zsh (without python or homebrew dependencies) so it’s ready to mass-enroll with MDM.

Comment: Is your question “how to rollout/deploy mandatory Google FileProvider enablement to Macs across an organization via MDM and/or bash script?”  This question is confusing with all the Google Drive history preface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my edit might solve this confusion :)